# Linking slideshow thumbnail to slideshow views content

Tags: views

I have a view containing pictures from a content type "Slideshow". When I click the Slideshow title in a view containing the slideshows, it takes me to the slides from that slideshow. However, I want to get rid of the title and be able to click the picture instead of the title so I can do the same thing. Could you please tell me how I could do that?

Comment: Are you using Views Slideshow or just Views to create a list of the "Slideshow" nodes?

Comment: Views to create a list of Slideshow nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will earn time by coding a small [hook_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) that calls your JavaScript plugin for your slideshows. Then, you will be able to configure easily your module and your link.
Views can be really harmful when you try to do things like slideshows.

Just pick a jQuery plugin from the ones listed on [13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials) and the rest of the job will be easy.

Comment: But it surely can be done without writing code. I mean, it just needs to be linked to the parent node ID, but I don't know how to do that. I did have a normal table with objects whose names I linked to each of the objects details through NID. Something similar should be doable here as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you should be able to go to your view, edit the image field (the one that shows the Slideshow thumbnail), find the heading 'Link image to' and change it from the default 'Nothing' to 'Content'.